# How can I export Time Series NDVI yearly monthly per region in single CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, ndvi, region

Hi i need single csv with months and years like this for per region  but i couldn`t export can some one help me
[image]

```
var regions = table.filterBounds(geometry);
Map.addLayer(regions);
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(regions);
};


var NDVI_C = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13A1')
    .select('NDVI')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate(ee.Date('2003-01-01'), ee.Date('2022-01-01'))
    .map(clipToCol);

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2001, 2022);

var ndvi= NDVI_C.map(function(image) {
  return image.multiply(0.0001).set(
      'system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
   // var by years =dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y,y,'year'))
    
    return months.map(function (m) {
      return ndvi
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
        .median()
        .set('month', m).set('year', y);
  });
}).flatten());

var vegseri = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2003-01-01','2022-01-01')
.select('NDVI')
.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

//var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(vegseri, table,
//ee.Reducer.mean(),1000, 'system:time_start')
//.setChartType('LineChart')
//.setOptions({
  //title: 'NDVI series changes',
  //hAxis: {title: 'Time Series'},
  //vAxis: {title: 'NDVI Values'},
  //lineWidth: 2,
//});
  //  print(chart);

Export.table.toDrive({collection:vegseri, description:ndvi,  selectors:'month,value'});
```

link this code is:https://code.earthengine.google.com/a07671837c5a2277c1222117d3a197f7

Answer (score 1):

You came quite far in the implementation. The last step is to calculate the NDVI for each region. I assume you want the median value there too. In addition to this, you have to do some massaging of the data, remove year/months without any data and rename the columns.

```
var ndviByMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var median = ndvi
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
        .median()
        .set('month', m).set('year', y)
      return median
        // Allows year/month without imagery to be filter out
        .set('empty', median.bandNames().size().eq(0)) 
    })
  }).flatten())

var byRegion = ndviByMonthYear
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('empty', 0)) // Remove year/month without imagery
  .map(function(yearMonthNdvi) {
    return yearMonthNdvi
      .reduceRegions({
        collection: regions.select(['FID_1'], ['region']), 
        reducer: ee.Reducer.median().setOutputs(['ndvi']), 
        scale: 500
      })
      .map(function (feature) {
        return feature
          .copyProperties(yearMonthNdvi, yearMonthNdvi.propertyNames())
      })
  })
  .flatten()
  
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: byRegion,
  description: 'ndvi',
  selectors: ['region', 'year', 'month', 'ndvi']
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b8dc0821a1c325a07c66323d11c9058

Comment: thank you very much yes i need this code but i have 21 regions that i must use this  rule for that .setSeriesNames(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22'])    So in which line i must add this?   @Daniel Wiell

Comment: I don't quite follow that last part. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: In CSV my reagions not sort by name and also start by number 0 but i need start by number 1 untill 22 and sort  @ Daniel Wiell

Comment: You want the `region` column in the CSV to contain labels?

Comment: yes in need  the number of my regions in this CSV too @Daniel Wiell

Comment: You have to name your regions somehow. In this case, you could simply create a list of names and look up by `FID_1`, since it's an index. `0 -> A`, `1 -> B`, etc. Something like this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3d1708bc97ec8dbcedf1b2c9935610cb

Comment: And how can i display the months 1 to 12 for the first region, then the months 1 to 12 for the second region, etc.? Like the image I uploaded  @Daniel Wiell

Comment: please tell me why this code dosen`t have any data in CSV https://code.earthengine.google.com/7413c60c20e56b1033f246d77b276e5f  @Daniel Wiell

Comment: The above code is the same NDVi code only for Change Temperature @Daniel Wiell